# Can I Mongoose indexes at both the Schema path level AND Schema level?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

According to Mongoose documentation about https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes:

" With mongoose, we define these indexes within our Schema at the path level or the schema level."

Just to clarify: that means that I *cannot* have two different indexes, one defined in the Schema path level and another in the Schema level? For example:

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String,
    tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
  });

  animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one at the field level is just sugar syntax for the `.index` function.

So if you already defined the index on the field with the `.index` function, it won't do anything  more.

In your example, the index on `tags` will be created as well as the index on `name + type`.

This :

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String,
    tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
  });
```

Is equivalent to this :

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String,
    tags: { type: [String] }
  });

animalSchema.index({ tags: 1 }); // schema level
```

Comment: Great! So I'm assuming that the answer is yes: you can define indexes in both places...  Thanks!